# How to get a textarea's value and put it into another textarea using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

I am trying to develop a url decoder using Javascript but my code won't work, can anyone tell me how to do it,thx

```
<textarea id="input"></textarea>
<br />
<button id="yes" align="center" onclick="getInput(document.getElementById('input')">Click to transfer</button>
<p>The decoded URL：</p>
<textarea id="decode"></textarea>
<script>
    function getInput(inputElement) {

        var decoded = "";

        if inputElement == 0 {

            document.write("You didn't input anything");

        } else if {

            var uri = inputElement;
            var uri_decode = decodeURIComponent(uri);
            var uri_encode = encodeURIComponent(uri)

            document.getElementById("decode").innerHTML = uri_decode;
            document.getElementById("encode").innerHTML = uri_encode;

            decoded = uri_decode;

        }
        return decoded;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Typo in your code :
onclick="getInput(document.getElementById('input'), no enclosing parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming logic is correctly done in your original code.

Since it is a text area,you must use `value`

Try :

```
document.getElementById("decode").value = uri_decode;
```

More Properties at [HERE](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_textarea.asp)

Comment: Please do not suggest w3schools.com.Read this :
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W3Schools

Comment: @Stillakid Alright :) But,the properties can be used as a reference . Anyways,suggestion take! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

even though im still quite new to this, i think i found a few mistakes, im not sure if it will fix you're problem, but you should give it a try.

1.
`<script>`

would need to be:

`<script type="text/javascript">`

otherwise your browser doesnt know what type of script it needs.

2.`if inputElement == 0 {`

would need to be:
"
`if (inputElement == 0) {`

3.`} else if {`

should be `} else {`

closing the script stays the same :
`</script>`

i hope this works, if it doesn't then tell me.

Answer (score 0):

In your *else if*, you didn't specify an if-statement.
Guess you meant *else*

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to use the jQuery Api.

Once you click a button you can pick it up using

```
$('#transfer').click(function() { }
```

Then simply collect the text from the first text box using

```
var url = $('#urlToDecode').val();
```

then write the 'url' variable into the second text box using

```
$("#decodedURL").val = url;
```

Hope that helps! :) Note: you will need to link to the jQuery API which is hosted by Google.